# Dynamically/Programmatically Authorize Inbound Traffic IP Address Access to EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud-hosting, dynamic-ip

Is there a programmatic (api) method of authorizing a particular IP addresses to access a particular EC2 instance, e.g. for RDP.

This could be done by either creating a security group with the IP address and adding the security group to an instance. Or, this could be done, by adding an IP address to a particular security group.

Comment: Yes. Boto3 library (Python) can do what you are asking for.

Comment: You can do this programmatically via any of the AWS SDKs, or via the AWS CLI tool.

Answer (score 1):

Use [create-security-group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-security-group.html) if a security group doesn't already exist and then [authorize-security-group-ingress](http://authorize-security-group-ingress) to add the IP address to the group. Finally, if necessary, associate the security group with the instance with [modify-instance-attribute](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/modify-instance-attribute.html).

The APIs are similarly named and a [Java example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/create-security-group.html) is available.